# Running AppleScript When Inserting a Blank CD

Tags: applescript, cd-burning

I want to automatically burn a cross-platform data CD with the same contents each time a blank disc is inserted, and eject it when done. To that end I created a very simple AppleScript that does just that:

```
do shell script "/bin/bash -c 'hdiutil burn ~/Desktop/catalog.iso'"
```

It works fine from the AppleScript editor. If I click "Run" with a blank CD inside, it burns the CD with the data from the .iso and ejects it upon completion.

However, if I select "Run `~/Desktop/burn.scpt`" as the default action when inserting a blank CD, nothing happens. I actually have to open the AppleScript editor and select "Run". How can I make it actually run the script?

[image: blank cd dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Open burn.scpt in the AppleScript Editor and save it as an Application. Then select burn.app as the desired action on CD popup.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it still doesn't work! If I insert the CD and then double-click the newly created Burn application it works, but it doesn't work if I auto-run it on insert.

Comment: Hmm. What version of the OS are you running? I'll try to replicate the problem.

Comment: Running Mac OS 10.7.2

Comment: 'Doh. Sorry, I can't replicate, because my machine running 10.7.2 doesn't have a CD drive. Maybe someone else can help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keyboard Maestro to make a macro to run your shell script.

First make the macro with an 'Execute Shell Script' action like so:
[image]

Then use start a new 'Script Editor.app' file and paste this:

```
tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine"
    do script "Copy Disc"
end tell
```

^Note the name of the script above (Copy Disc) must correspond to the name of your macro in KM.

Next export with File > Export and use the File Format: Application. I recommend not code signing.

Only thing left is to make sure you set it:
[image]

There's probably a more direct way to do it, but this works for me.